# Fitting new amount of features to GradientBoostingRegressor produces error. Using Cross_validator does not

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've got a GradientBoostingRegressor thats already been fit with data. I want to try fitting a different amount of features to it. But I get an error saying there is a feature miss match between the input and the estimator.

However, when I pass the new X values (new n features) to cross_validater, there is no error.

What does cross validation do that I'm not doing when I use GradientBoostingRegressor.fit(X,y) ??

I have tired fitting the new features to GradientBoostingRegressor.init.fit(X,y) first with no luck?

Any one have any experiance with this at all?

Answer (score 0):

If any one has this issue, I have managed to overcome it by using:

sklearn.base.clone

[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.clone.html)

-- Constructs a new estimator with the same parameters.

Clone does a deep copy of the model in an estimator without actually copying attached data. It yields a new estimator with the same parameters that has not been fit on any data.